# Store does not have a valid reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux

This is first time i'm working with React and Redux. I haven't able to find error around it.

"webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-error-overlay/lib/index.js:1446 Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers."

This is reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({});

export default rootReducer;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the object is empty.

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({});
```

This error will show.

add some data in it like:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import foo from '../foo' //this is your reducer

const rootReducer = combineReducers({foo});
export default rootReducer;
```

**reducer example**

```
//reducer/foo.js
export default function foo(state = null, action) {
     switch (action.type) {
         case 'MY_ACTION_TYPE':
           return action.payload
     }
     return state;
 }
```

Comment: I have tried your solution, but it didn't work, it show the same error. combineReducers({foo: {}});

Comment: @vuogvuog updated my post, foo represent your reducer

Comment: @vuogvuog can you post here your reducer?

Comment: ??. I have posted it above

Comment: @vuogvuog That's not a [reducer](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers).

Comment: @vuogvuog as Asaf Aviv mentioned, this is not a reducer, iv added a reducer example also

Comment: post your folder structure here